# Setting up DNS on mobile broadband and/or setting a system wide DNS address?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, dns, ethernet, mobile-broadband

I am using a Huawei E3131b 3G dongle to connect to internet. I'm having troubles setting up DNS servers that persist across reboots.

Manually specified DNS servers are not used at all if I use the bundled application that came with the dongle to connect to internet (which identifies the dongle as a modem and connects as a virtual ethernet adapter.)

However if I use windows 7's inbuilt software tools (which identifies the dongle as mobile broadband) then I can use other DNS servers apart from the ones allotted by the ISP. I can go and change them in the IPv4 settings. But there's a catch here. These dns settings do not persist across reboots or if the dongle is plugged out and then re-plugged. I've to change the DNS manually every time this happens.

So I was wondering if there was a method or a software that will "lock" my dns entries and save them across reboots or if there is a way to set a system-wide dns address so that only specific dns servers are always queried from my laptop irrespective of the adapter or the network interface i'm using to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the dongle (imp), do not dial.

Go to Control Panel → Network and Internet → Network Connections

Select Local Area Connection 3 (or whichever has a Max suffix). If the dongle is not connected, it will be one less, and hence invalid.

Select Internet Protocol Version 4 → Properties

Specify the desired DNS.

[image]